# Function parameter passing in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

The following code represents an attempt at a minimal, reproducible example which compiles and runs as expected.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import  model_selection as skms

N = 20

ftr = np.linspace(-10,10,num=N) # ftr values
tgt = 2*ftr**2 -3 + np.random.uniform(-2,2,N) # tgt =func(ftr)

(train_ftr, test_ftr, train_tgt, test_tgt) = skms.train_test_split(ftr, tgt, 
test_size = N//2)

model_one = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(train_ftr, train_tgt, 1))
preds_one = model_one(test_ftr)
```

Where the following are of type numpy ndarrays.

```
train_ftr
test_ftr
train_tgt
test_tgt
```

My question relates to the output of the last line `preds_one` wrt the second last line `model_one`. In the last line, how can you pass a parameter `test_ftr` to the function `model_one` defined in the second last line when `model_one` is a composite function? That is, what is `test_ftr` actually being passed to?

Comment: `model_one` is not a composite function, it is a class instance of the `numpy.poly1d` class. A class instance can be callable, depending on whether you have its `__call__` method defined (in this case: yes). So calling a class instance such as `preds_one = model_one(test_ftr)` is a simplified expression of `preds_one = model_one.__call__(test_ftr)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.poly1d` returns a `callable` object. That is, it can be called like a function (i.e. it is a function). Objects in Python are callable if they have a `__call__()` function.

By calling `model_one(test_ftr)`, you are actually calling `model_one.__call__(test_ftr)`, which is a method that this object has.

Every function in Python is an object with a `__call__` method.